# How to calculate the "cross join" of permutations faster?

Tags: r, data.table, combinations, permutation, cross-join

I have a data.table with 2 columns.
"events, group"
There could be up to 20 rows, or as few as 1.
Each of that events is classified into a given group.
The data.table is already sorted by group.

For example:

```
Events   group   
     a       1
     b       2
     c       2
     d       2
     e       3
     f       3
```

What I need to do is:
- For each group compute all permutations of its events.
- Compute all cross combinations of that permutations.
- Later for each "combination" I will further compute additional.

In my example I would get this permutations (shown rowwise)

```
a 

b  c  d 
b  d  c 
c  b  d 
c  d  b 
d  b  c 
d  c  b 

e  f 
f  e
```

And finally this crosscombination of the rows:

```
a  b  c  d  e  f 
a  b  d  c  e  f 
a  c  b  d  e  f 
a  c  d  b  e  f 
a  d  b  c  e  f 
a  d  c  b  e  f 
a  b  c  d  f  e 
a  b  d  c  f  e 
a  c  b  d  f  e 
a  c  d  b  f  e 
a  d  b  c  f  e 
a  d  c  b  f  e
```

The way I have achieved it was:

```
library(data.table)
library(arrangements)

myDT <- data.table(ll=letters[1:6], gr=c(1,2,2,2,3,3))   #simple example 

dos <- function(x,y) {
  temp <- expand.grid(1:nrow(x),1:nrow(y))
  cbind(x[temp[,1],], y[temp[,2],])
}

fun2 <- function(z) Reduce(dos,z)


permu <- function(xx )  {   # alternative to compute the permutations
  if (length(xx)==1) {
    matrix(xx)
  } else if (length(xx)==2) {
    rbind(c(xx[1], xx[2]),c(xx[2], xx[1]))
  } else {
  permutations(xx) 
} } 

f1 <- function(x) {fun2(tapply(myDT$ll,myDT$gr, permutations))}
f2 <- function(x) {fun2(myDT[,.(.(permutations(ll))),by=gr]$V1)}
f3 <- function(x) {fun2(myDT[,.(.(permu(ll))),by=gr]$V1)}
```

The first method uses tappply.
The second method tries to make the calculations in a data.table's way.
The third method tries to make calculations faster for small groups.
I'm using permutations from the package "arrangements" because it's fast.  Feel free to use whatever package (such as  RcppAlgos) or code your own algorithm.
I don't mind if the output is a matrix, a data.table, a list, transposed, if you use other containers or if it's ordered in a different way.

```
myDT <- data.table(ll=letters[1:6], gr=c(1,2,2,2,3,3))

f1()      982.05us      1.88KB    501ms 
f2()        2.38ms     52.27KB    501ms 
f3()        1.83ms     52.27KB    501ms
```

In order to benchmark it we can use a larger example.

```
myDT <- data.table(ll=letters[1:15], gr=rep(1:5, times=rep(5:1)))  # larger example

               min     median   mem_alloc     gc total_time 
f1()       381.5ms     911ms       22.3MB       1.82s 
f2()       123.5ms     185ms       22.3MB       580.22ms
f3()        99.3ms     130ms       22.3MB       505.05ms
```

How can I do it faster? (also using less memory would be good)
If I try to do it with data.table(ll=letters[1:21], gr=rep(1:6, times=rep(6:1)) it takes more than 3 minute, way too long because in my real problem I need to perform the calculation 1 million times.

Comment: I don't know why permutations produce an error if I use numbers instead of letter for the events.  But it works well for rcppAlgos, though its syntax is more complex.  Using numbers makes no difference on speed. It also seems to be slightly faster if the events are factors.

Answer (score 2):

Sooner or later you are going to encounter out of memory problem and with `data.table(ll=letters[1:21], gr=rep(1:6, times=rep(6:1)))`, you are generating 24,883,200 rows (`prod(factorial(DT[, .N, gr]$N))`).

Anyway, iff it is **absolutely** necessary to generate all permutations, here is an option:

```
library(data.table)
library(RcppAlgos)
DT <- data.table(ll=letters[1:6], gr=c(1,2,2,2,3,3))
DT <- data.table(ll=letters[1:21], gr=rep(1:6, times=rep(6:1)))
#prod(factorial(DT[, .N, gr]$N))

CJ.dt_1 <- function(...) {
    Reduce(f=function(x, y) cbind(x[rep(1:nrow(x), times=nrow(y)),], y[rep(1:nrow(y), each=nrow(x)),]),
        x=list(...))
} #CJ.dt_1

system.time(
    ans <- do.call(CJ.dt_1, DT[, .(.(RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(ll, .N))), gr]$V1)
)

#   user  system elapsed 
#  16.49    4.63   21.15
```

Comment: OK, thanks, I know the problem with the large number of permutations. I will filter out some extreme cases. Anyway, I've found that your approach sometimes is slower than mine and it fails when the number of elements is just one.

Comment: Thanks, can you share the edge case?

Comment: For example with DT <- data.table(ll=letters[1], gr=c(1)) doesn't work. It seems trivial, but I need to apply the function to a very large dataset and some groups contain just one row.

Comment: Mixing your answer and mine I've found a better solution: CJ2 <- function(x,y) {cbind(x[rep(1:nrow(x), times=nrow(y)),],y[rep(1:nrow(y), each=nrow(x)),])}
ans <- Reduce(CJ2 , tapply(DT$ll,DT$gr, function(x) permutations(v=x)))